# Randomly assign Treatment dummy variables according to session

Tags: r, dataframe, dummy-variable

I would like to assign a dummy variable named "sender", however, I want to do it randomly within each session only and not the entire experiment.

Assume I have a data of 180 students. Each session has 18 students. Thus I have 10 sessions. Within each of these sessions, there should be 9 senders (value of 1) and 9 receivers (value of 0).

So far, I only managed to do this, with the entire experiment as follow:

```
va <- c(1,0)
df$sender[sample(1:nrow(df1), nrow(df1), FALSE)] <- rep(va, 90,90)
```

I am thinking of doing it in a primitive way by applying the same code above 10 times repeatedly for each session, but the data may get larger than that. I would be grateful for some help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure what your expected output is, but this should help you in the right direction:

```
students = 5 # per trial
trials = 3
senders = 2 # per trial

df = data.frame(studentID = seq(1,students*trials),session = 
                  rep(seq(trials), times = rep(students,trials)))

df$sender = unlist(sapply(seq(trials), function(x) 
        {as.numeric(seq(1,students) %in% sample(students,senders))}, simplify=F))
```

Output:

Now, we have got 3 sessions, each with 5 students and exactly 2 senders per trial.

```
   studentID session sender
1          1       1      0
2          2       1      0
3          3       1      1
4          4       1      1
5          5       1      0
6          6       2      1
7          7       2      0
8          8       2      1
9          9       2      0
10        10       2      0
11        11       3      1
12        12       3      1
13        13       3      0
14        14       3      0
15        15       3      0
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just one to clarify that it is my expected output! Thank you for a very neat code!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

# create example dataset
session_id = 1:10
student_id = 1:18

df = expand.grid(student_id=student_id, session_id=session_id)

# fix randomisation (to replicate results)
set.seed(259)

df %>%
  sample_frac(1) %>%                                     # shuffle dataset (i.e. resample 100% of rows)
  group_by(session_id) %>%                               # for each session id
  mutate(sender = ifelse(row_number() <= 9 , 1, 0)) %>%  # flag as senders the first 9 (random) rows
  ungroup() %>%                                          # forget the grouping
  arrange(session_id, student_id)                        # arrange columns (not needed; only for visualisation purposes)


# # A tibble: 180 x 3
#   student_id session_id sender
#        <int>      <int>  <dbl>
# 1          1          1      0
# 2          2          1      0
# 3          3          1      1
# 4          4          1      1
# 5          5          1      0
# 6          6          1      1
# 7          7          1      0
# 8          8          1      1
# 9          9          1      0
# 10         10         1      1
# # ... with 170 more rows
```